# Is there any way to speed up capturing?

Tags: loadout

Is there any way to speed up the capturing in Blitz or Competitve?

I heard rumors that taunting would increase the capturing speed. Is this correct?

Comment: Pretty sure the taunting thing is just some guy telling you to be more vulnerable during objective capture. You know how trolls are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually true.

Taunting when standing on a capture point speeds up capturing a 10%.

You can see it in the "Pro Tips" in game:

[image]

Comment: So that explains why I see people randomly taunting on points. Haha